# I want to check my webview is scrolled down or not

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I have a **`WebView`** `Fragment` in my application, I want to check, the user scrolled the **`WebView`** down or not ,for example if the user **scrolled down** my **`WebView`** , I want show a `Toast` message that "*you scrolled down*" I'm trying this for the past 3 days, I didn't get any proper solution. I have seen many tutorials and discussions, none of them are working for me. Is there any one who can help ?

> This is my fragment java code

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {

 public ProgressBar bar;
 public FrameLayout frameLayout;
 public tab1()
 {

 }

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, null);

     final SwipeRefreshLayout swipe =(SwipeRefreshLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh1);
     frameLayout=(FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frame1);
     bar=(ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
     final WebView view=(WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

     bar.setMax(100);
     view.loadUrl("http://facebook.com");
     view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
     view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view1,int progress){

            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bar.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress==100){

            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }

      super.onProgressChanged(view1,progress);
        }
    });

    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    bar.setProgress(0);

 swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            swipe.setColorSchemeResources(
                    R.color.pink, R.color.indigo, R.color.lime);

            String webUrl = view.getUrl();

           view.loadUrl(webUrl);
        }
 });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

> This is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.tab1">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
        android:progress="20"/>

</FrameLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</WebView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

> Error message after adding answer

```
Cast from null to OnScrollChangeListener requires API level 23 (current min is 15) less... (Ctrl+F1)
```

This check scans through all the `Android` `API` calls in the application and warns about any calls that are not available on all versions targeted by this application (according to its minimum `SDK` attribute in the manifest).  If you really want to use this `API` and don't need to support older devices just set the `minSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` or `AndroidManifest.xml` files.  If your code is deliberately accessing newer `APIs`, and you have ensured (e.g. with conditional execution) that this code will only ever be called on a supported platform, then you can annotate your class or method with the `@TargetApi` annotation specifying the local minimum `SDK` to apply, such as `@TargetApi(11)`, such that this check considers 11 rather than your manifest file's minimum `SDK` as the required `API` level. If you are deliberately setting android: attributes in style definitions, make sure you place this in a `values-vNN` folder in order to avoid running into runtime conflicts on certain devices where manufacturers have added custom attributes whose ids conflict with the new ones on later platforms. Similarly, you can use `tools:targetApi="11"` in an `XML` file to indicate that the element will only be inflated in an adequate context

Comment: Have you tried on scrollChanged method??

Comment: Actually i am new to Android,  i have tried, but actually don't knw how to implement that method for fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok try this

```
view.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int 
      oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

        }
    });
```

here view is your WebView object. :) its native method so it will work fine.

Comment: not working, what i actually want to do is, when the user scroll down the webview , i want to hide the actionbar

Comment: hey i just checked .... just add    view.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                
            }
        });

Comment: can you add your code in my code , and post as answer ?

Comment: @Jaison_Joseph check the answer

Comment: see my question, i got that kind of error after adding your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140224/discussion-between-abdul-kawee-and-jaison-joseph).